# Firefox starts in small window

Tags: firefox, window

Ever since the installation of 12.4, Firefox only starts in a small window. I'm getting really pissed about that. Does anyone know how to fix that?
Any kind of help would be really appreciated!!!

Comment: How did you installed Firefox? I guess, you are not using Ubuntu but another derivative such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Can you ensure this?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail like add a snapshot?Is it the case that even if you close the Firefox maximized,it starts in a small window?

Comment: yes it is, and no its precise ubuntu not kubuntu or lubuntu

Comment: Plz check the answer below and hope it helps

Comment: Should probably be closed as Too Localized, see [OP's answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/185625/12864).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happends when the `localstore.rdf` file is corrupted.

It is located in `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile_name>/`.

You can use either of the following solutions:

- **If you have a backup copy of `localstore.rdf`** file from a working profile, a quick remedy is closing Firefox and overwriting the localstore.rdf file in the Firefox profile folder with your backup copy.
- **If you don't have a backup copy** just delete the file from the path mentioned above, and Firefox will generate a new copy for you.
- **If you're using Firefox 15**, just reset the firefox profile from *History* > *Reset Firefox*.

  **Important Note** (if you're using *Reset Firefox*):

> All of your Firefox settings and personal information is stored in
>   your profile folder. The reset feature works by creating a new profile
>   folder for you while saving your:
>
> - Bookmarks
> - Browsing history
> - Passwords
> - Cookies
> - Web form auto-fill information
>
> The following items  are either NOT SAVED or set to their defaults.
>
> - Extensions and themes
> - Open tabs, windows and tab groups
> - Site-specific preferences, search engines, personal dictionary, download history, DOM storage, security certificate settings, security
>     device settings, download actions, plugin MIME types, toolbar
>     customizations and user styles
>
> After the reset is finished, your old Firefox profile information will be placed on your desktop in a folder named "Old Firefox Data."

**Source and Further Information:**

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Toolbar_customizations_reset_on_startup
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems

Comment: What about latest Firefox versions (55). Where does it keep the last session window size and location parameters?

Comment: Nuke hours of firefox customizations/settings is a lousy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the OS have the ability to save the last thing you do which an application

so try to maximuze you firefox and then close it and when you open it. it will open in large window.

I hope this helps

**Edit**

ok here is the link http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

you have to use command line to set your firefox width and height

you can find out your screen width height and set is according to that

```
firefox -width 800 -height 500
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you think i havent done that? i do it everytime

Comment: Where does Firefox keep its default windows size?

Answer (score 1):

This problem actually went away after I opened Firefox, maximized it, then closed it and I repeated the process multiple times.